# The elements of sp.vcov in package mgcv?

Tags: r

Consider the code below for fitting a generalized additive model:

```
require(mgcv)
attach(data)
mod = gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2), method="REML")
```

The estimated covariance matrix for the log smoothing parameter estimates is given by:

```
 sp.vcov(model)
```

The output is:

```
           [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 0.45465578 1.551113e-01 0.02868156
 [2,] 0.15511135 4.122903e+05 0.07369381
 [3,] 0.02868156 7.369381e-02 0.02221753
```

Why it's a 3x3 matrix, while there are two smoothing parameters in the model and so I expect it to be a 2x2 matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?sp.vcov`:

> If the scale parameter has been (RE)ML estimated (i.e. if the method was "ML" or "REML" and the scale parameter was unknown) then the last row and column relate to the log scale parameter.